# Magento 2.4 upgrade error - sortorder is not allowed

Tags: magento, magento2

ive just updated Magento to 2.4 all went well but when i put Magento into dev mode i got the error

Element 'plugin', attribute 'sortorder': The attribute 'sortorder' is not allowed.
Line: 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid Document Element 'plugin', attribute 'sortorder': The attribute 'sortorder' is not allowed. Line: 14 in /home/public_html/staging/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:169 Stack trace: #0

i have been to the file location for the error but can not find anything or any answers online

many thanks

Comment: Hello, It's better to ask here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an error in one of your projects di.xml files.

It seems you need to either correct or remove the sort order attribute in a plugin definition, eg.

```
<plugin name="my_plugin_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginA" sortorder="10" />
```

Should be (notice the camel case sortOrder)

```
<plugin name="vendor_module_plugina" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\PluginA" sortOrder="10" />
```

Comment: Thank you was a extension in app/code causing it, never would of found it without your help